# How to add or modify the list of websites associated with a password

Tags: macos, catalina, password

I'm using Catalina's password functionality (via macOS settings). I have an account (username, password and website) where I want to modify the existing website, or delete it, or add another website. I have other accounts where there are multiple websites listet. Somehow it doesn't seem possible to modify this manually though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, Apple does not permit manually revising this, even in macOS Ventura.

To add a website: Create a new saved password with the same username/password and correct website

To delete a website: If the website is the only one on the record, just delete the record. If there are two, and you need to delete just one of them, then you can edit the record and right click the website and remove it.

If you need fine grained control, you can export a CSV, edit it, and re-import into Safari.

Comment: Thank you. Do you by chance know if the export includes the 2FA code?

Comment: It does, yes - The CSV will have a column OTPAuth that includes an otpauth:// setup URL.

Comment: Note that if you choose to manually re-create the entry instead of re-importing the CSV, you'll need to only paste in the value in the "secret" parameter of the URL, not the entire URL.

Comment: Trying to see if I understand this… I have 2 domains that use the same login; one local and one normal. If I delete one, and go to safari to log in and add again, I use the login of the other but it still creates a separate entry. Do I need to use a CSV import to get this to work?

Comment: @liteowl My answer was outdated and I revised it, you can now remove logins from existing websites - you still cannot add them. Edit the password and then right click the domain to remove it

Comment: Thanks for your response — I see I misunderstood the point. I am trying to merge logins where I have the same password for two different domains (because they are the same service). I don’t need to remove anything.

Comment: @liteowl there is no way to do this unfortunately